# ruby-on-rails params missing or value is empty (when using with angularJS form)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, require

I am a newbie at ruby on rails and I am currently developing a part of portal. I have encountered some errors which I could not find an solution.

First error:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: user):
app/controllers/admin/manage_users_controller.rb:97:in `user_params'
app/controllers/admin/manage_users_controller.rb:32:in `update'
```

Second error:

```
ArgumentError (When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.):
app/controllers/admin/manage_users_controller.rb:32:in `update'
```

My manage_users_controller:

```
def edit
  if request.format.json?
   t = @user
   @user = {:id => t.id, :email => t.email}
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => @user, :status => 200}
    format.html
  end
 end

def update
  @user.attributes = user_params
  if @user.save
   respond_to do |format|
    format.json {render :json => {:redirect_to => admin_manage_users_path}, :status => 200 }
   end
  else
   respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => {:errMsg => print_out_message('form-update','user'), :errors => @user.errors}, :status => 400 } 
   end
  end
 end

 def user_params  
  return params.require(:user).permit(:user_id, :email)
 end
```

for the first error, I am not sure why the param is missing.
for the second error, I have read on other posts that I need to use the require and permit method in my user_params. however, I still cannot figure out what exactly is the problem.

Any help would be deeply appreciated. Thank you.

--------------------------UPDATE-----------------------------

edit.html.erb in the view

```
  <div class="row" ng-controller="AdminManageUsersCtrl">
     <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="rs-content" data-ng-init="loadUser()">
       <div class="portlet listing" cg-busy="loadUser" ng-cloak>
         <div class="portlet-body">
          <form name="form" ng-submit="uploadUser()" confirm-on-exit>
           <%= render "admin/manage_users/form" %>
           <div class="row row-space-top-1">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
             <button type="submit" class="btn red-mint" ng-click="form.$setPristine()">Update</button>
             <%= link_to "Cancel".html_safe, admin_manage_users_path, :class => "btn dark btn-outline" %>
             <%= link_to 'Remove', URI::unescape(admin_manage_user_path(:users => '{{user.id}}')), :method => :delete, :class => "pull-right btn red btn-outline", :data => {:confirm => 'Are you sure you want to delete this user?', "ng-click"=>"form.$setPristine()"} %>
            </div>
           </div>
          </form>
         </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

And the _form.html.erb

```
 <div class="col-md-12 space-1" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : form['email'].$invalid }">
  <label class="control-label">Email</label>
  <div>
   <div class="input-icon right">
    <i ng-show="form['email'].$invalid" class="fa fa-warning tooltips" data-original-title="{{errors['email']}}" data-container="body"></i>
    <input ng-model= "user.email" name="email" type="text" class="form-control">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

in the app.js

```
$scope.uploadUser = function() {
  $scope.errors = [];
  AdminManageUsers.$patch('update', $scope.user).then(function(response) {
   $window.location.href = response.redirectTo;
  }, function(response) {
   angular.forEach(response.data.errors, function(errors, key) {
    $scope['form'][key].$invalid = true;
    $scope.errors[key] = errors.join(', ');
   });
   alertMessage.danger(response.data.errMsg, 1, 10000);
  });
 }
```

And this is the routing in route.rb

```
  resources :manage_users, :only => [:index,:destroy], :param => :id
   match "manage_users/data" => "manage_users#data", via: [:post], :defaults => { :format => 'json' }
   match "manage_users/load" => "manage_users#load", via: [:get], :defaults => { :format => 'json' }
   match "manage_users/:id/edit" => "manage_users#edit", via: [:get]
   match "manage_users/:id/update" => "manage_users#update", via: [:patch]
```

Sorry I am posting a lot of code, but I think they are all related. 
To be honest, I am actually trying to follow the style of coding my mentor adopted, so he used angularJS to design the form, so I still have some trouble understanding how everything links together.

Comment: Please post your form code and the generated params in the question.

Comment: I am a newbie at ruby on rails - Welcome, thank you for having the patience to ask a question instead of giving up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error itself is caused by your [`strong_params`](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) method:

```
params.require(:user).permit(:user_id, :email)
```

Specifically, the *require* argument means that the controller is expecting a params hash which has `"user"` as the main element:

```
params: {
  "user" => {
    "user_id" => "1",
    "email"   => "test@email.com"
  }
}
```

As you don't have the above set up, the error comes back that you don't have the `user` in the params hash.

---

**Solution**

Make sure you're passing the right object through your params. You should have the following set up:

```
#app/views/admin/manage_users/edit.html.erb
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :email %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Along with this, the entire way you're doing this is flawed; you'd be better using the following:

```
#app/controllers/admin/manage_users_controller.rb
class Admin::ManageUsersController < ApplicationController 
   respond_to :js, :json, :html
   before_action :set_user

   def edit
     respond_with @user
   end

   def update
      respond_to do |format|

        if @user.update user_params
          format.json {render :json => {:redirect_to => admin_manage_users_path}, :status => 200 }
        else
          format.json { render :json => {:errMsg => print_out_message('form-update','user'), :errors => @user.errors}, :status => 400 } 
        end

     end
   end

   private

   def set_user
      @user = User.find params[:id]
   end

   def user_params  
       params.require(:user).permit(:user_id, :email) #-> Ruby automatically returns the last line of a method
   end
end
```

Comment: I found my error, it was in the app.js where I created the ManageUserFactory method. I specified the name in the factory method as 'manage_user' but in the controller I was passing (:user) to the params. I should pass 'manage_user' to the params and the problem is solved. Thanks.